# How do i pass two points to the method?

Tags: c#, winforms

What I tried so far is this: the way I did it now it will get the same point twice.
I need to pass it two points each time. I could do in the second `clouds[i+1]` but then I will get sometime index out of...error I think.

```
for (int i = 0; i < clouds.Count; i++)
{
    ExtendPoints(clouds[i], clouds[i]);
}
```

clouds is `List<PointF>`
ExtendPoint get `PointF,PointF`

the way I did it now it will get the same point twice.
I need to pass it two points each time. I could do in the second `clouds[i+1]` but then I will get sometime index out of...error I think.

EDIT**

This is the method:

```
private static List<PointF> ExtendPoints(PointF pt1, PointF pt2)
        {
            float x = (Math.Max(pt1.X, pt2.X) - Math.Min(pt1.X, pt2.X)) / 2 + Math.Min(pt1.X, pt2.X);
            float y = (Math.Max(pt1.Y, pt2.Y) - Math.Min(pt1.Y, pt2.Y)) / 2 + Math.Min(pt1.Y, pt2.Y);
            var pt3 = new PointF(x, y);
            var extendedPoints = new List<PointF> { pt1, pt3, pt2 };
            return extendedPoints;
        }
```

Comment: Your intent is not clear. Can you give a sample of what you want to pass into method? E.g. if you have points A,B,C. It should be A,B and B,C?

Comment: You need to pass _any_ two points?

Comment: Update my question added the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var maxIndex = clouds.Count - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < maxIndex; i++)
{
    ExtendPoints(clouds[i], clouds[i + 1]);
}
```

It will call `ExtendPoints(clouds[0], clouds[1])`, then `ExtendPoints(clouds[1], clouds[2])` and so on.

If you need to pass each point only once, so call `ExtendPoints(clouds[0], clouds[1])`, then `ExtendPoints(clouds[2], clouds[3])` and so one change `i++` to `i += 2`:

```
var maxIndex = clouds.Count - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < maxIndex; i += 2)
{
    ExtendPoints(clouds[i], clouds[i + 1]);
}
```

Comment: +1. I've removed "clouds." from condition which seem to be intent of local variable.

Answer (score 3):

If you have three points A,B,C and you want to pass two consecutive pairs A,B and B,C then simply change condition to `i < clouds.Count - 1`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < clouds.Count - 1; i++)
{
    ExtendPoints(clouds[i], clouds[i + 1]);
}
```

That will not throw `IndexOutOfRangeException` when you will try to get point at index `i + 1`